# How can I make my crystal have more of a glass effect to it and be able to see inside it

Tags: texturing, displacement, glass

I'm following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-zpR1E84nQ

I have a black cube inside the crystal, but its quite hard to actually see it, I've tried to give it more of a glassy effect but cant quite get it to look the way I want.

Also my crystal feel blurry and not as sharp as I would like it

Could anyone offer any advice?

Crystal shading:
[image]

Render output:
[image]

Comment: I would start by lowering the roughness on the Principled BSDF. Also, the "correct" IOR for glass is 1.450 - you have it set to 2 - perhaps bring it closer to 1. Lastly, the mix with the Emission Shader is causing you to lose some of the Glass effect - you should try using a layer weight node (fresnel or facing, whatever looks best) as a mix factor.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how that works?

Comment: You mean the Fresnel? Pause the video at exactly 2:20

Comment: This is a crystal, not glass. Many crystals have IORs much higher than glass, around 2. As far as I can tell, OP has correctly copied the reference for the layer weight mix portion

Answer (score 2):

The *Strength* value of the *Bump* node is too high. You probably forgot the change it.

In the video, a value of `0.150` is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the crystal to be more of a realistic clear crystal as opposed to a stylized mat one, you should instead use a "Glass" shader. This handles PBR crystals much better than Principled.

For best result, look up the IOR of the crystal you want to mimic, but a good starting point is around 2.

This is a quick example comparing my suggestion on the left and a copy of the current setup on the right:

[image: example]